# When is a polynomial irreducible over a field with characteristic $\neq2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

When is a polynomial irreducible over a field with characteristic $\neq2$?

Help me a hint. I have no idea.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah, over $\mathbb{Q}$ we have Eisenstein's Irreducibility Criterion

Comment: There is no simple recipe - there are many ways to check though, the most popular of which is called Eisenstein's criterion. Another is called finding a root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can, in turn, check if this polynomial has roots on this field or not.

If $charF$ is not too large, it is not terribly difficult to check this.